# How to define / characterize a curved line graph

Tags: curvature, geometry

I have data that consist of multiple curved lines between point *A* and point *B*. I would like to categorize these lines into a number of groups.
The groups are:

- straight
- slight break
- heavy break
- early break
- late break

A visual interpretation of the lines can be found below:

[image]

However, I am having difficulty describing the lines / categories. I am only interested in the shape (not the length).

I tried rotating the images 90 degrees and describing them as PDFs of a beta distribution with different values for alpha and beta. However, this approach is not feasible for `straight`, `slight break` and `hard break`.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Upper-left is like an arc of a circle of radius $R$, while the rest can be almost described as an arc of some forwards or backwards going [spiral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765595/spiral-equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to evaluate the curvature of the lines, roughly speaking the second derivative of the points of the curves w.r.t. the arc-length.

Assuming that you know the points of the curves and you can introduce the arc-length variable, the parametric expression of a curve become $\mathbf{r}(s)$, and the curvature is $k(s) = |\mathbf{r}''(s)|$. Since you're interested only in the shape of the curves and not in their dimension, you can normalize them to get unit-length curves, so that $s \in [0, 1]$.

Once you have the function $k(s)$, you could evaluate both the "amount of curvature" of the trajectory and the "distribution in space" of the curvature along the trajectory:

- the amount of curvature gives you the distinction between slight and heavy, and could be computed as an example with the integral of $k(s)$ with $s \in [0,1]$, $K = \int_{0}^{1} k(s) ds$;
- the distribution of curvature could be evaluated as a sort of weighted mean of curvature over the length, as an example $M_1 = \frac{1}{K}\int_{0}^{1} s k(s) ds$ (something like a first momentum, but you could try high-order momentum as well), that is a valid expression for $K \ne 0$, i.e. for every line that is not straight (but for a straight line, with no curvature at all, it's meaningless to talk about curvature). With $M_1$ approaching $0$ (or at least $<1/2$) you could talk about Early Break, with $M_1$ approaching to $1$ (or at least $>1/2$) you could talk about Heavy Break.

**Discretization.** You can use the numerical method you like the most to get a discrete (or at least, finite dimensional) approximation of your continuous curves, and the numerical schemes that better fits the approximation method.

**Comments.** If you start with these kind of images, you may need to compensate for perspective, before performing any kind of computations about the trajectories.